# What does "Mine is a watery pit / Painless with immense distance" from Alt-J “Taro” mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, alt-j

> Mine is a watery pit
> Painless with immense distance

Is this an allusion to something or were the lines written originally by the songwriters?

Comment: This question would be improved if you included the whole sentence (which does not stop at "distance"), and gave a bit more context about what the song is about and why these lines are causing you trouble.